# How to write a custom formatter in VSCode that inherits from existing formatters?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, yaml, formatter

I have HTML code with YAML front matter for content and I would like to format both parts concurrently. I have created a custom syntax and highlighting works well.

How to register a new formatter for the custom file type, which would inherit from existing formatters in VSCode?

That would look like this:

```html
---
title: "Title"
description: "Long and arduous description"
x:
  bodyclasses: home
---
{{extends "page.html"}}

{{block Body()}}
<article class="main">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates, magni sapiente voluptas magnam omnis nisi aut amet! Facilis exercitationem voluptatem dolorem asperiores accusamus vitae, maiores veritatis, animi perspiciatis dolor commodi!</p>
</article>
{{end}}
```

Here is my current `jet.tmLanguage.json` (the format above is for Go Jet HTML template files with YAML as a front matter):

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/martinring/tmlanguage/master/tmlanguage.json",
  "name": "HTML Template (Jet)",
  "scopeName": "text.html.jet",
  "fileTypes": [
    "jet"
  ],
  "patterns": [
    {
      "yaml.format.enable": true,
      "include": "#frontMatter"
    },
    {
      "html.format.enable": true,
      "include": "text.html.basic"
    }
  ],
  "repository": {
    "frontMatter": {
      "begin": "\\A-{3}\\s*$",
      "contentName": "meta.embedded.block.frontmatter",
      "patterns": [
        {
          "include": "source.yaml"
        }
      ],
      "end": "(^|\\G)-{3}|\\.{3}\\s*$"
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe the easy solution could be the best one... why not put the yaml as the first (comment) element

Comment: @Akxe I updated the post to include my current setting, which I believe does just that. However, I am trying to inherit formatters from both HTML and YAML for two different parts, which I hoped would be inherited. Syntax highlighting seems to work.

Comment: I am not familiar with how this work, but I know there are many multi formatters that can format template string in JS/TS when they are prepended with a comment something like `/*yaml*/\`... yaml config ...\``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a few options for you: *(in order of least to most effort)*

1. You can make a PR to the [Microsoft VSCode Repository](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues) and see if they can add in a formatted for that file type. (see if they can merge this into VSCode)
2. You can install a VSCode plugin to apply custom formatting to your files, it provides a tutorial to configure the format tool as well, you can install it [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jkillian.custom-local-formatters).

> I don't run VSCode for Golang development, but I do see the [Golang Plugin in the VSCode market](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=golang.Go) and it says it formats `tmpl` files but doubt it would format the `.jet` file.
> An issue could be made with [Golang community plugin](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go) to add support for that as well.

3. Another option is to switch to one of the many IDEs like [JetBrains GoLand](https://www.jetbrains.com/go/) (can recommend) that has support for formatting the Jet HTML Templates. (Only pointing this out if you are not attached to VSCode)
4. Read through the ["Creating a Formatter Plugin"](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2016/11/15/formatters-best-practices) documentation and build a VSCode Extention. Then you could publish this extension for others.

Comment: I am following the Route 4, will post when done.